# Create php-based blog on host without database access

Tags: php, hosting, blogs

I am going to create a blog-like application for a University.  I have been given access to their server, but I was not granted access to their databases.  The server has PHP installed, so I plan on utilizing that.

At the very least, I would like to give the user the ability to post a blog.  Though this is not a strict requirement, the ability to comment on each blog post would be nice.

If I were to keep the application very simple, I could just use flat files to store the blog posts.  Using flat files would be fairly unwieldy when incorporating comments, however.  Another option would be to use SQLite, though I have not confirmed whether or not that is installed on the host.

Neither of the above options are ideal.  I have also been looking at Google's Blogger API.  This seems like a good option, but the limitations are fairly, well, limited (maximum of 100 posts, 1MB per post, etc).  Are there any other sites out there that provide blogging web-services?  I am certainly not looking for stuff like Wordpress.com or Blog.com, as I want to write custom software.  I am strictly looking for a way to store and organize the information, for free.  Google Storage also sounds like an option, but I don't want to start paying if the site gets too much traffic (although it will be a pretty low-traffic site).

Thanks for any ideas!

**EDIT: Looking for a FREE solution!**

Comment: sqlite'd be best if you can't get access to a "real" database. problem is loading the sqlite driver into php. your Uni may not allow non-approved modules or dynamic module linking at all. but if they've got the mysql/postgres/etc... drivers loaded, nothing says you HAVE to use **THEIR** databases... you could potentially connect to a db anywhere on the net.

Comment: You could always let another service handle comments, like Disqus: http://disqus.com/

Comment: Or consider using a free online database.

Comment: It would not be very wise to store in files as this will likely not perform very well. you'll be opening and seeking thru files and closing them all too often

Comment: FREE= some one else is paying, now why would they want to do that?

Comment: FREE doesn't necessarily mean someone else is paying.  Does Google make money by providing Gmail for free?  Absolutely.  Same goes for their Blogger/Storage services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go with Google's Blogger API (https://developers.google.com/blogger/).  In my question, I mentioned that the limitations include a maximum of 100 posts.  I was incorrect; it actually has a limitation of 100 blogs per account (that's a bunch!), and each blog can have an unlimited number of posts and comments.  I think this option is great for anybody looking for free storage for a blog, as long as you are willing to conform to their data model.

For anybody that might come across this question, the Blogger API allows you to perform CRUD operations on a blog using a RESTful interface.  Google stores all of the data for you.  If you don't mind your application making a request out to the series of tubes that is the internet, then the Blogger API will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options which are using File Based DB or Network Based.
SQLite or Access are your options which are file based DBs. For your case, SQLite is better.

Other option is buying or renting (or find a free one) a DB or server from somewhere and using it on your app. You will connect this server instead of connecting localhost. Make sure the hosting provider allows remote access to the database, I mean ports for the DB should be accessible.

Comment: +1 but remote DB is the only good answer. File DB is the solution only when you are really out of other options.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the Rocket Store suggestion was downvoted. It is essentially a speedy key/value store wrapped up so you don't have to go through the hassle of writing a nice encapsulation of the file operations yourself. Code quality also seems solid. It's not a full NoSQL database but it gets the job done for simple tasks where speed is important.

I just tried it on a Raspberry Pi 2 and it inserted 35000 records (admittedly simple ones) per second. The syntax is simple, and the authors page has more code examples than most other projects I have seen.

If you're not looking for remote storage, then Rocket Store ("paragi\rocket-store") definitely seems worh checking out.

(source: https://packagist.org/packages/paragi/rocket-store)

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple mechanism in PHP to the purpose of storing of retrieving large amounts of data, in flat files. It's fully independent of other services.

It's simple to use and does the job of storing and retrieving records, using the file system, in a very easy to use manner. On top its lightning fast.

You can find it here: https://packagist.org/packages/paragi/rocket-store

You just need to include one file to use it, and there are no dependencies.

Comment: Dear stackoverflow user i think you should allow your library to store files and i geuss it is not easy to understand ow it work, even i passed on github to view it i discovered it was not possible for an other person who is not you to understand it

Comment: I'm always open to suggestions. Please don't hesitate to help me make the text clearer. But I really don't know how to make it simpler!? 
->post(<collection name>,<key>, <array of data>) Thats it!